# Spring integration: Is it possible to make the sender wait till the task executor queue/thread is free.

Tags: spring-integration

Is it possible to make the sender wait till the task executor queue/thread is free.

The task executor is as follows:

```
<int:channel id="inputRequestChannel">
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="validationWorkers"/>
   </int:channel>
   <task:executor id="validationWorkers" pool-size="5" queue-capacity="10"  rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>
```

Using the above configuration some packets are lost which are sent to inputRequestChannel.

How to ensure that the no packets are lost?

Which rejection policy is suitable?

Comment: `>How to ensure that the no packets are lost?` That's not possible; once they are in the executor's queue they are subject to loss if the server crashes. You need to show the rest of your configuration in order for someone to make a suggestion about avoiding message loss.

Answer (score 1):

Would you mind to share some test-case to reproduce and really understand that packets are lost. Not sure what is the "packet" matter per se...

You can consider to use a `CallerBlocksPolicy` instead though:

```
/**
 * A {@link RejectedExecutionHandler} that blocks the caller until
 * the executor has room in its queue, or a timeout occurs (in which
 * case a {@link RejectedExecutionException} is thrown.
 *
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 3.0.3
 *
 */
public class CallerBlocksPolicy implements RejectedExecutionHandler {
```

Comment: Thanks Artem Bilan. Issue got resolved. It seems that the issue was the main app was exiting, for verification I was printing the message received message, before the messages in the queue channel are consumed and message is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Artem's answer, here is my example of using `CallerBlocksPolicy`:

```
    @Bean(name = "inChannel")
    public MessageChannel inChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }


    @Bean(name = "asyncChannelsExecutor")
    public Executor asyncChannelsExecutor() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(3);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(3);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(2);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("TTT");
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new CallerBlocksPolicy(30_000));
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean(name = "asyncOutChannel")
    public MessageChannel asyncOutChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.executor(asyncChannelsExecutor()).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow asyncFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("inChannel")
            .transform(dtoTransformer)
            .channel("asyncOutChannel")
            .handle(handler)
            .get();
     }
```

Note that `org.springframework.integration.util.CallerBlocksPolicy`
is provided by Spring Integration. The `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler` is core Java platform interface.